# Angular model does not change(update) after changing url

Tags: javascript, angularjs

SOLUTION: `var deferred2 = $q.defer();` This should be inside method _getSpecificPerson() because when I visit other Person promise in alredy resolved. This way I create new deferred object each time.

I have some list, for example list of persons. If I visit details page( different view ,different controller) I have url like : #/PersonDetails/0c4274ed-ae76-4648-bba4-434a3040b9c5, but when a return and want to see some other person details I get same page like before althougt I can see I sent already get request for getting other person. It seems angular ignores new data, if it has some data populated before.
This is relevant code if needed:

```
 personModule.controller("PersonDetailsController", function ($scope, $http, dataService, $routeParams) {


var id = $routeParams.PersonId;
var myPromise = dataService.getSpecificPerson(id);
myPromise.then(function (result) {
    var returnedPerson = result;
    if (returnedPerson.AllXml) {
        $scope.OnePerson = JSON.parse(returnedPerson.AllXml);
    }

});
```

});

```
   personModule.factory('dataService', function ($http,$q) {

  var deferred = $q.defer();
 var deferred2 = $q.defer();
    var _getPersons= function() {

        $http.post(ROOT + 'Home/GetPersons').
            then(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                deferred.resolve(data.data);

            },function () {
            deferred.reject();
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }

    var _getSpecificPerson = function (id) {
        var dataString = {
            id:id
        }
        $http.post(ROOT + 'Home/GetPerson', dataString).
           then(function (data, status, headers, config) {
               deferred2.resolve(data.data);
           }, function () {
               deferred2.reject();
           });
        return deferred2.promise;
    }
return {
    getPersons: _getPersons,
    getSpecificPerson:_getSpecificPerson
    }
```

});
I tryed put my scope assigment inside of $scope.$apply() but I get $digest already in progress:
$digest already in progress
EDIT: Factory function returns good data from service but when I do myPromise.then(function(result){ inside of my controller result is cached! (but when I console.log(data.data) inside factory method it _getSpecific person returns up-to-date data!

Comment: can you show us what the data in returnedPerson looks like? is it JSON?

Comment: Yes, it is Json...everythig is great if I refresh page...

Comment: But when I visit personA, and return to list of persons and then visit personB , I send request and get response for person B but $scope.OnePerson dors not update in template. I tried doing $scope.apply but I doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I everything is JSON you should be able to write

```
$scope.OnePerson = returnedPerson.AllXml;
```

Also you could simplify your service

```
var _getSpecificPerson = function (id) {
    var dataString = { id:id };
    return $http.post(ROOT + 'Home/GetPerson', dataString);
}
```

Because the post method returns a promise.
In your controller you must make this change for it to work:

```
var returnedPerson = result.data;
```

Comment: Factory function returns good data from service but when I do myPromise.then(function(result){ inside of my controller result is cached!

Comment: Are you really sure that $scope.OnePerson gets the new data? If you do a console.log($scope.OnePerson) inside of the if-statement does it show the new data?

Comment: No $scope.OnePerson gets old data, server returns new data if I console.log(data.data) a get FRESH data...but inside controller myPromise.then(function(result)........result is OLD.

Comment: Here is the problem, my promise function is called before faytory method. How this is possible?

Comment: It's difficult to see what's wrong when you can't see all of the code.

Comment: This is real all the code. I found solution! var deferred2 = $q.defer(); This should be inside method _getSpecificPerson()

Comment: Well done! If you had simplified the code as I suggested it would have worked too ;-)